# Javascript/HTML5 - Trying to make a simple game AI

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-ai

My concept is rather simple. Animate an image one way, then make it come back.

```
var xPos = 10;

function main(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Initialize images
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "goomba.png";

    c.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    c.drawImage(img,xPos,10);


    //increment coordinates
    if(xPos <= 250){
        xPos+=2;
    }
    else if(xPos >= 250){
        xPos-=2;
    }
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

I already know what the problem is with my code. When the xPos goes over 250, then the second **if** statement becomes true. However, once it goes below 250, the first **if** becomes true again.
So I know what the problem is, I just dont know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using `else if()`? http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptelseif.php

Comment: Yes, it had the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a velocity variable (positive is right, negative is left, amplitude is number of pixels to change each loop):

```
var xVelocity = 2;
```

And use it to determine what to add to the xPos each loop:

```
xPos += xVelocity;
```

Then set it based on xVelocity and xPos so that the image will "bounce":

```
if(xVelocity > 0){
    if(xPos > 250){
        xVelocity = -2;
    }
} else {
    if(xPos < 10){
        xVelocity = 2;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/uweyam/1/edit

is this what you want?  Or do you want to stop it at the left edge?

UPD.:  You can also make it bounce like this -  http://jsbin.com/uweyam/4/edit